# Convert nested dictionaries to a dataframe and join with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
my_dict = {'Red': {'Red': {'A': 91, 'B': 279, 'C': 296, 'D': 516}, 'Amber': {'A': 229, 'B': 273, 'C': 273, 'D': 529}}, 'Amber': {'Red': {'A': 191, 'B': 323, 'C': 329, 'D': 634},  'Green': {'A': 137, 'B': 212, 'C': 222, 'D': 430}}, 'Green': {'Red': {'A': 50, 'B': 254, 'C': 299, 'D': 463}, 'Amber': {'A': 84, 'B': 235, 'C': 244, 'D': 364}}}
```

but much bigger.

I have a dataframe df1 that looks like below but much bigger (hundreds of rows) and with  more columns (10s)

```
C1    C2      dim1 unique_no
Amber Red     F     1
Red   Green   T     2    
Green Red     T     3 
Red   Amber   F     4 
Red   Red     T     5 
Green Amber   T     6
```

I like to create columns A, B, C and D in df1 based on values in my_dict

I think converting my_dict to a dataframe and them merging the dataframes will be one way of achieving this

I have tried to convert my_dict to a dataframe using

```
df2 = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v).T for k, v in my_dict.items()}, axis=0)
```

df2 appears as this:

```
              A    B    C    D
Amber Red    191  323  329  634
      Green  137  212  222  430
Green Red     50  254  299  463
      Amber   84  235  244  364
Red   Red     91  279  296  516
      Amber  229  273  273  529
```

I want df2 to be like this:

```
  C1    C2    A    B    C    D
Amber Red    191  323  329  634
Amber Green  137  212  222  430
Green Red     50  254  299  463
Green Amber   84  235  244  364
Red   Red     91  279  296  516
Red   Amber  229  273  273  529
```

so I can join df1 with df2

Comment: are you looking for `df2 = df2.rename_axis(['C1','C2'])` ?

Comment: add reset_index() at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using reset_index():

One way to do it is by using reset_index() and naming the two new columns 'C1' and 'C2'

Example:

```
df2.index.rename(['C1', 'C2'], inplace=True) # rename the index of df2 'C1' and 'C2'
df2 = df2.reset_index() # reset index
```

Then you can join df1 and df2.

Hope this helps.